# Is there a way to execute a set of GDB commands when a break point is hit?

Tags: gdb

I'm trying to achieve the "Semihosting" like feature by registering a set of commands associated with a specific break point, like:

```
print buffer[0]
cont
```

So the plan is having analog values dumped into the GDB client console in realtime, thus making the development process easier.

Is it possible for GDB to execute above example commands when the breakpoint on line 38 (eg.) is hit? (I will need to run different set of commands on another break point)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each breakpoint you add in gdb has a number. You can see the numbers with `i b` (short for `info breakpoints`). Suppose you want to add commands to breakpoint number 2, just type `commands 2` and press ENTER. Now, type the commands you want gdb to run when breakpoint 2 is hit (one per line). When you want to finish entering the commands, type `end`.

Tip: You can add the `continue` command before `end` if you want gdb to continue execution instead of stopping. That is, if you only added to breakpoint to add commands to it but you don't want execution to stop there. For instance, if you just want to print the value of some variable, or even if you want to create another breakpoint but only if some specific code path is reached first. The possibilities are endless.